# Can I use Infinity and -Infinity as an initial value for Max and Min variables?

Tags: javascript, infinity

I thought that it would be acceptable to initialize my Max value to
-Infinity but this did not turn out to be the case in JavaScript.

If Infinity is considered a number type why can't I use it in my comparisons?

```
  var windowStart =0, sum =0, max = -Infinity
  for(windowEnd=0;windowEnd<k-1;windowEnd++)
  {
    sum += arr[windowStart]
    if(windowEnd>k-1)
    {
      if(sum > max)
        max = sum
      sum -= arr[windowStart]
      windowStart += 1
    }
  }

  return max;
```

Thanks to the community I noticed that I jumped the gun in posting my question and did not do an appropriate amount of my own debugging. Thank you all for your quick answers.

Comment: You can `let max = -Infinity;`

Comment: You can use `Infinity` in comparisons. Please show the code where you're using `Infinity`.

Comment: `max = -Infinity` is perfectly legal, as is `-Infinity < 4`, for example. What exact problem are you getting?

Comment: @freddyhaug Please paste the code into your question instead of posting a screenshot of it.

Comment: Okay, thank you for confirming this, it must just be some separate error in code. I'll poke around thank you thank you sorry sorry

Comment: @weltschmerz Okay, I made the change

Comment: This condition `if(windowEnd>k-1)` never passes, as the loop breaks when `windowEnd == k-1`.

Comment: ooooooo I see I made the for loop stop at k-1 and not arr.length. Thank you Teemu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Infinity as you intended:

```js
Math.min(Infinity, 10)
// => 10

Infinity < 10
// => false
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's indeed already being used as default min and max values even in native Math.min and Math.max function implementations

```
Math.min(); // Infinity
Math.max(); // -Infinity
```